# Pycharm doesn't show errors in inspection results

Tags: pycharm

I have several files with python errors in them (unresolved references, if that matters), so I ran Inspect code in order to get a list of all the errors. Unfortunately, it looks like they don't show up:

[image: inspection results]

The errors definitely do exist, because when I open a python file with errors in it, they are shown:

[image: file error analysis example]

Am I missing some hidden option, or this this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically on your default settings `code inspection` and `current file analysis` should work on the same [inspection profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/code-inspection.html#profiles).

For `current file analysis` you can check profile by typing `ctrl+alt+Shift+H` and clicking `Configure inspections` link.

[image]

For `code inspection` you set profile after selecting `Inspect Code` from `Code` menu element.

[image]

**My observations**

After changing inspection rules for `current file analysis` I don't see any impact on [Severity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/code-inspection.html#severities). I tried to restart IDE but nothing helped. **It looks like a bug.**

However, if I turn on/off the rule with a checkbox, it makes changes either on `current file analysis` or `code inspection` (they are running in the same inspection profile). It is ok, so the problem is only with severity.

[image]

Good news is that changing inspection rules works for `code inspection`. You can try to make `code inspection` similar to `current file analysis` (but not vice versa and that's a bug).

[image]

Notice that unresolved references by default are just warning, so `code inspection` works well.

PS My IDE version is 2016.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I needed to "Add content root" under "Project Structure" in Preferences. I had no content root.